# Running a robosuite python script gives error 'cl.exe failed with exit code 1'

Tags: python-3.x, visual-c++, pip, pycharm, mujoco

I have installed robosuite for mujoco on Windows through the PyCharm package manager. Whenever I try to run a test script, I get the error:

"distutils.errors.CompileError: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe' failed with exit code 1"

I have tried:

- Reinstallung the Visual Studio Code C++ Compiler
- Manually running the cl.exe in question
- Manually adding the path to cl.exe to my PATH
- Running PyCharm and installung robosuite as an admin

All of the error descriptions I can find online are exit code 2 and happen while installing, not while actually running the program.

Any help is appreciated!